# Magento 2 - How to get attribute options array for inserting the data using rest api

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I have json array for attribute options which is showing below:

```
"options":[
 {
  "label":"string",
  "value":"string",
  "sort_order":0,
  "is_default":true,
  "store_labels":[
   {
    "store_id":0,
    "label":"string"
   }
  ]
 }
],
```

So I need that types of data by the magento 2 collection for particular attribute id or code.

I need to add/edit attribute options data using rest api in magento 2

Please provide me collection, thanks in advance.

Comment: How about your issue?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we need take a look: **Log in Magento Admin > Choose a product > ADVANCED SETTINGS > Custom Options**:

[image]

We can see some fields, we need to fill in these input fields.

Second, we have the APIs for updating the custom options: http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#resource_catalogProductCustomOptionRepositoryV1

- *POST*: **/V1/products/options**
- *PUT*: **/V1/products/options/{optionId}**

For example:

```
{
  "option": {
    "product_sku": "string",
    "option_id": 0,
    "title": "string",
    "type": "string",
    "sort_order": 0,
    "is_require": true,
    "price": 0,
    "price_type": "string",
    "sku": "string",
    "file_extension": "string",
    "max_characters": 0,
    "image_size_x": 0,
    "image_size_y": 0,
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "string",
        "sort_order": 0,
        "price": 0,
        "price_type": "string",
        "sku": "string",
        "option_type_id": 0
      }
    ],
    "extension_attributes": {}
  }
}
```

- `product_sku`: Product SKU
- `option_id`: We can get by **/V1/products/{sku}/options**
- `title`: Title of the custom option.
- `type`: Input Type: Text, File, Dropdown, Radio, etc
- `sort_order`: Set the order of custom attribute
- `is_require`: Required or not
- `price`: Price for the custom option
- `price_type`: Fixed or Percent
- `sku`: (updated later)
- `file_extension`: can be empty, allowed file types: pdf, jpg, ...
- `max_characters`: can be empty, used for Input type: Field, Area.
- `image_size_x` and `image_size_y`: blank if it is not an image.
- `values`: can be empty, used for Select Type: Dropdown, Radio Buttons, Checkbox, Multiple Select. We need to set the title, price type, Sortorder, etc.

Comment: How can i get options images, dependency to custom option in rest api I am using Mageworx product option extension for adding extra product option like images and   dependency????